# How to detach Firestore Listener in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling to figure out how to detach a firestore listener to a query.

I'm running a number of Firestore listeners on clients, which I want to be able to detach by calling a method when triggered by the 'master' once that part of the show is done.

I'm setting it up like this:

```
Query query = db.Collection("houston").Document(player.playerStory).Collection("story").WhereEqualTo("likefish", "yes");

        ListenerRegistration fishYes = query.Listen(snapshot =>
```

And I *think* I need to detach it by calling fishYes.Stop();

...but I don't know how to make a reference back to the original listener in order to do so.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The [ListenerRegistration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/firestore/listener-registration) is all you need.  Call `Stop()`, and you're done.  There's no need to build a reference to the original query - the ListenerRegistration object knows what to do.

Comment: EDIT -

Ah ok. I get it. I was setting them up from inside an 'if' statement, so couldn't access the ListenerRegistration. If I restructure that more sensibly, we're golden it seems. 

Still learning - thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still struggling to access the object. 

So, I took it out of the `if` statement in the method when it was instantiated and also declared it as part of the class scope :

``public ListenerRegistration fishYes;``

and now I *think* I should be able to access it in another method in the same class using ``fishYes.Stop();`` - but I can't. 

I know I'm missing something about scopes here, but I can't quite figure out what it is...

Comment: That sounds like a new and unrelated problem to the question you have here. Please post a new question in that case.